# Appcache is not caching files

Tags: php, caching, browser-cache, html5-appcache, cache-manifest

I'm trying to use appcache, and it doesn't work. This is my manifest file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
stylecache.css
stylecachemobile.css
customalert.js
fonts/*
images/*
stylefonts.css
footer.php
header.php
home.php
index.php
logout.php
matchscout.php
myteam.php
navbar.php
pitscout.php
upload.php


NETWORK:
stats.php
config.php


FALLBACK:
/html/ /offline.html
```

This page is cache.appcache. This is what I have for my HTML heading:

```
<html manifest="cache.appcache">
```

I have tried all, but all it says is cannot open page because you are not connected to the internet. My links are www.example.com/index.php?page=home
and it opens home.php with header.php, navbar.php, and footer.php. I did access the page first to let it cache, but nothing works.

EDIT:

It did something, because whenever I change page (index.php?page=home to index.php?page=anotherpage), it closes all sessions. I removed the manifest at the  tag, and it doesn't do that anymore